# Gitlab Runner in Kubernetes Could not resolve host

Tags: kubernetes, dns, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have deployed a Gitlab Runner in our Kubernetes Cluster with the [Helm Chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html#installing-gitlab-runner-using-the-helm-chart)

Now i try to build a image with kaniko. But the runner can not resolve the url of my gitlab server:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)
on gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-d7996895b-7lpnh nY2nib3b
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab
Using Kubernetes executor with image gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug ...
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-ny2nib3b-project-2-concurrent-0w2ffw to be running, status is Pending
Running on runner-ny2nib3b-project-2-concurrent-0w2ffw via gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-d7996895b-7lpnh...
Fetching changes...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/my-repo/.git/
Created fresh repository.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@XXX.XY:8443/my-repo.git/': Could not resolve host: XXX.XY
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

When i connect to the pod and try `nslookup XXX.XY`:

`nslookup: can't resolve 'XXX.XY': Name does not resolve`

I have already solved some problems but here I have no idea. DNS works in other PODs.

Edit:

on a working busybox pod the output of nslooup is

```
nslookup google.de
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      google.de
Address 1: 2a00:1450:4001:816::2003 fra16s07-in-x03.1e100.net
Address 2: 172.217.18.3 fra15s28-in-f3.1e100.net
```

Comment: provide the output of the pods where the `nslookup` works. is the server running inside the cluster or outside? are the `coredns` pods in the `kube-system` namespace up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With us it was a DNS configuration problem. The nodes were not configured correctly and Alpine seems to follow the standard a bit more closely than others.

I have looked at the /etc/resolve.conf file of the not working PODs. The Problem was the last (wrong) Domain under "search".

Comment: I'm new to gitlab and kubernetes. I have the same problem as the OP because one of the servers in resolv.conf is resolving my domain name to my gitlab instance wrongly. How do I change it permanently for that pod?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using v12.3.0, then you ran into a bug: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/issues/96